# Did Kylo Ren read Poe Dameron's mind?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren, poe-dameron

In [*The Force Awakens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_The_Force_Awakens), [Kylo Ren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylo_Ren) is able to successfully retrieve the information from Poe Dameron that he was looking for during interrogation.  It at first appears that Kylo's using the force to torture [Poe Dameron](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Poe_Dameron) and as Poe screams the scene changes.  What's not totally clear is whether Kylo tortured Poe into talking or if Kylo just straight ripped it from Poe through some kind of mind-rape telepathy.

[image: Poe Dameron being tortured]

Did Kylo Ren read Poe Dameron's mind?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novelization)) (considered a canon source of information about the movie) indicates that yes, Poe's mind was indeed violated by Ren using the dark side of the Force to read his innermost thoughts and discover his secrets.

> *Slumped and shackled in the seat, Poe was still breathing. Beyond
> that, he no longer cared much what happened to him. It wasn’t his
> fault, he kept telling himself. **For an ordinary person, no matter how
> strong they thought themselves, resisting the probing of a creature
> like Kylo Ren was simply not possible.** He had tried. There was no
> shame in the failure.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novelization))</sup></sub>

The [junior novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel) also gives a pretty solid account of what transpired

> *He reached toward the prisoner with gloved fingers. Through them Ren
> channeled currents of pain from his own bottomless well—**and tendrils
> that would probe the depths of Dameron’s weak mind.***
>
> *“Tell me. Tell me.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens: A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: This was more clear after I finished watching the second half of the movie again where Kylo tries to mind-rape Rey.  I kept ending up only seeing the first half of the movie a few times, because of my kid's bed time.

Answer (score 0):

It could have gone either way. Kylo Ren is able to search through people's minds and get the information that way, but occasionally people are able to prevent that if they have a strong enough will in their mind. Another way that force users, or Kylo Ren in this case can do this is by **basically** torturing their minds until they give up the information that way. However this is not used often by the Jedi unless necessary because if this mind "torture" continues too long it will destroy their mind -- leave them with brain damage, as pointed out by Mace Windu to Anakin Skywalker and Obi-Wan Kenobi -- when they chose to use it against Cad Bane in Star Wars: The Clone Wars.